# Rename A Sub-Directory the parent folder name if NOT called "info"

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, rename

Is it possible to make a batch file that will rename a folder if does not have a specific name? 

EG:
Parent Directory

 - - - > info

 - - - > randomfoldername

I have many folders that follow the above pattern. What I would like to do is make a batch file that will rename "randomfoldername" in this structure. There is always two folders in the Parent Directory, one is always "info" and the other changes for each case. Is there a method within a batch file that I could use to always rename the "randomfoldername" directory? I was thinking something along the lines of,

IF NOT == "info" THEN ren... ect.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can first check if folder exist then rename folder

```
  if not exist c:\info ( call random.bat )
```

random.bat:

```
dir /A:D /b | findstr.exe /n /R "." > s:\sites\file-count.txt

FOR /F "tokens=1-10 delims=:" %%A IN ('type "s:\sites\file-count.txt"') do 

set NUMBER-OF-FILES=%%A

FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%number-of-files%) DO CALL RENAME.bat %%A
```

rename.bat

```
    :rename
FOR /F "tokens=1-10 delims=:" %%A IN ('type "s:\sites\file-count.txt" ^| 
findstr "%1:"') do ren %%B %RANDOM%%%B
```

also u can use free tool like [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php)
that app has cli for use in bat file [here](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Command.php)
also You can use powershell script like

```
$a = test-path c:\info
 if ( $a -eq "True" ) { Write-Host nothing to do } Else { gic -directory path | %{$n="$pwd\$((get-random).tostring())$($_.name)";$_.moveto($N)} }
```

Comment: I've edited my description of the problem, its not that I want to rename info to pictures but that I want to rename the folder that is not called info into something else. Thanks for your reply anyways!

Comment: @Eamon changed just for bat file and script change to your path you want

Answer (score 0):

Next script starts with basic checks on [command line parameter](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) passed into.

`FOR /F` [loop against the results of another command](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) (`dir`) used. Next explanation *stolen* ([see dbenham's original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29329745/3439404)) :

> `FOR /R` (as well as the simple `FOR`) begin iterating immediately, before
>   it has finished scanning the disk drive. It is possible for the loop
>   to reiterate the already named file! This would cause it to be renamed
>   twice, giving the wrong result. The solution is to use `FOR /F` with
>   command `'DIR /B'`, because `FOR /F` always processes the command to
>   completion before iterating.

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set "ParentDirectory=%*"
if "%ParentDirectory%"=="" goto :usage1
if not exist "%ParentDirectory%\" goto :usage2
if not exist "%ParentDirectory%\info\" goto :usage3
set "SpecificName=Desired Name"

set /A "count=0"
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /B /A:D "%ParentDirectory%\"') do set /A "count+=1"
if %count% neq 2 goto :usage4 

for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /B /A:D "%ParentDirectory%\"') do (
    if /I not "%%~G"=="info" (
        if /I not "%%~G"=="%SpecificName%" (
            echo renaming "%ParentDirectory%\%%~G" to "%SpecificName%"
            rename "%ParentDirectory%\%%~G" "%SpecificName%"
        ) else (
            echo renamed already: "%SpecificName%"
        )
    ) 
)
:endlocal
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:usage1
echo no paramater
goto :endlocal

:usage2
echo "%ParentDirectory%" folder does not exist
goto :endlocal

:usage3
echo "%ParentDirectory%\info" folder does not exist
goto :endlocal

:usage4
echo "%ParentDirectory%" folder contains %count% subfolders 
goto :endlocal
```

**Output**:

```
==>29376745.bat
no paramater

==>29376745.bat x y
"x y" folder does not exist

==>29376745.bat d:\test
"d:\test\info" folder does not exist

==>md "d:\test\info"

==>29376745.bat d:\test
"d:\test" folder contains 6 subfolders

==>29376745.bat d:\test\29376745
renaming "d:\test\29376745\currentName" to "Desired Name"

==>29376745.bat d:\test\29376745
renamed already: "Desired Name"

==>
```

Required reading (indexes only):

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)